# Background color is only on top

Tags: html, css, background, background-color, nav

I need some help from you. I think all is OK, but it isn´t working. On the top and at the end is only rectangle with dark blue color. Is problem with navigation menu and his slider? I think a don´t have any object that block background color, I don´t have any ideas. Can you help me with this problem? Thank´s for responses!

````
 <head>
    
<link rel="icon" href="/minimenu.png">
 </head>
 <body style="background-color:darkblue;"><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xC42G9x/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Trulli" width="155" height="">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="/welcome.php">
                      
                     <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Home
                       </span>
                   </a>
                 
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Homework
                       </span>
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                       Grades    
                       </span>
                   </a>
                   
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Timetable
                       </span>
                   </a>
                  
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-leanpub fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Learning
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Games
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
             <p hidden>TU SA ZACINA SUBMENU</p>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 1
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 2
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p hidden>TU SA KONCI SUBMENU</p>  
           </ul>

           <ul class="logout">
               <li>
                  <a href="/index.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Logout
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>  
           </ul>
       </nav>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
 </body>
   </html>
   <style>@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:darkblue;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
 
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
</style>```
````

Comment: I think it's just your main menu img, chek it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    
    <link rel="icon" href="/minimenu.png">
     </head>
     <body style="background-color:darkblue;"><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xC42G9x/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Trulli" width="155" height="">
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <a href="/welcome.php">
                          
                         <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Home
                           </span>
                       </a>
                     
                   </li>
                   <li class="has-subnav">
                       <a href="#">
                           <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Homework
                           </span>
                     </a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="has-subnav">
                       <a href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                           Grades    
                           </span>
                       </a>
                       
                   </li>
                   <li class="has-subnav">
                       <a href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Timetable
                           </span>
                       </a>
                      
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">
                           <i class="fa fa-leanpub fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Learning
                           </span>
                       </a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">
                           <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Games
                           </span>
                       </a>
                   </li>
                 <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                 <p hidden>TU SA ZACINA SUBMENU</p>
                   <li>
                      <a href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Submenu 1
                           </span>
                       </a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                      <a href="#">
                           <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Submenu 2
                           </span>
                       </a>
                   </li>
                 <p hidden>TU SA KONCI SUBMENU</p>  
               </ul>
    
               <ul class="logout">
                   <li>
                      <a href="/index.php">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i>
                           <span class="nav-text">
                               Logout
                           </span>
                       </a>
                   </li>  
               </ul>
           </nav>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
     </body>
       </html>
       <style>@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
    .fa-2x {
    font-size: 2em;
    }
    .fa {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60px;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:20px;
    }
    

    .main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
    width:250px;
    overflow:visible;
    }
    
    .main-menu {
    background:darkblue;
    border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    width:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
    transition:width .05s linear;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
    z-index:1000;
    }
    
    .main-menu>ul {
    margin:7px 0;
    }
    
    .main-menu li {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    }
    
    .main-menu li>a {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    color:#999;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
    transition:all .1s linear;
     
    }
    
    .main-menu .nav-icon {
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    width:60px;
    height:36px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:18px;
    }
    
    .main-menu .nav-text {
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:190px;
     font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .main-menu>ul.logout {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    }
    
    .no-touch .scrollable.hover {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    }
    
    .no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    }
    
    a:hover,a:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    nav {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    -o-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    }
    
    nav ul,nav li {
    outline:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    .main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#5fa2db;
    }
    .area {
    float: left;
    background: #00008B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    @font-face {
     font-family: 'Titillium Web';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 300;
     src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
    }
    </style>
```

Just change background color from (class area) and choose the color you want and every thing will be okay

**Before**

```
    .area {
    float: left;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

**After**

```
    .area {
    float: left;
    background: #00008B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you want to do**
[I created an example for you](https://codepen.io/gulsenkeskin/pen/bGrgjoo)

```
<head>
    
<link rel="icon" href="/minimenu.png">
 </head>
 <body><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xC42G9x/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Trulli" width="155" height="">
           <ul style="background-color:darkblue;">
               <li>
                   <a href="/welcome.php">
                      
                     <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Home
                       </span>
                   </a>
                 
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Homework
                       </span>
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                       Grades    
                       </span>
                   </a>
                   
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Timetable
                       </span>
                   </a>
                  
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-leanpub fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Learning
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Games
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
             <p hidden>TU SA ZACINA SUBMENU</p>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 1
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 2
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p hidden>TU SA KONCI SUBMENU</p>  
           </ul>

           <ul class="logout">
               <li>
                  <a href="/index.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Logout
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>  
           </ul>
       </nav>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
 </body>
   </html>
   <style>@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:darkblue;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
 
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
</style>
```